# React-Redux: How to actually update a state of redux store which has dependency on other values of the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to using React-Redux. Hence, I'm facing some problems with this particular situation. My Redux Store is something like this:

```
{
    info: {firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', email: abc.xyz@gmail.com, name: 'abc xyz', id: 145},
    userInfo: {firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', email: abc.xyz@gmail.com, contactNumber: 1234567890, country: 'India'}
}
```

Now, I receive both these details from different pages. I store them on the store and make API calls using react-redux to update the store data. So, I receive both of these data using a separate API call. Now, when I update the userInfo payload, I successfully can update my userInfo store state. But, the firstName and lastName are 2 fields which are common. So, what should be the best practice to update the info, every time I update the userInfo, because they have to be in sync and same.

Pasting some of the redux code for reference:

**reducer.js** (for info)

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const initialState = {
  email: null,
  firstName: null,
  id: null,
  lastName: null,
  name: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_INFORMATION: {
      const { info = {} } = action;
      return { ...info };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducer.js** (for userInfo)

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const initialState = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    contactNumber: null,
    country: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.USER_INFORMATION: {
      const { userInfo = {} } = action;
      return { ...state, ...userInfo };
    }
    case actionTypes.GET_USER_INFORMATION_ERROR:
    case actionTypes.PATCH_USER_INFORMATION_HEADER_ERROR: {
      const { error = {} } = action;
      return { ...error };
    }
    case actionTypes.PATCH_USER_INFORMATION_HEADER: {
      const { userInfo: { data = {} } = {} } = action;
      return { ...state, ...data };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Please help me with the best practice to update both these data whenever the other one is updated to keep the data in sync. TIA.

Comment: Are you using `combineReducers` utility ? It takes an object with multiple reducers reducers.

Comment: @Akhilesh Yup, I'm using a combined reducer.

Answer (score 1):

For a more reducer-centric approach, use another reducer(as a wrapper) to handle cases where data needs to be shared across reducers, like this:

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    info: infoReducer,
    userInfo: userInfoReducer
});

function specialCaseReducerWrapper(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SOME_SPECIAL_ACTION": {
            return {
                // specifically pass state.userInfo as an additional argument
                info: infoReducer(state.info, action, state.userInfo),
                userInfo: userInfoReducer(state.userInfo, action)
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function rootReducer(state, action) {
    const intermediateState = combinedReducer(state, action);
    const finalState = specialCaseReducerWrapper(intermediateState, action);
    return finalState;
}
```

For reference, check [Beyond combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers)

Answer (score 1):

> what should be the best practice to update the info, every time I update the userInfo, because they have to be in sync and same

The best practice is to **never** keep duplicate data in state. You are already going through a lot trying to synchronize it, and it will get even worse with time. You are very likely to run into situations where data is desynchronized and you or someone else working at this code might simply just forget to synchronize it again after implementing new changes. These bugs are hard to catch too

If you have common data between slices of your store, you need to leave only 1 instance of it